# Lights appear when run in the player although Editor playmode seems to be dark enough [Unity 5]

Tags: lighting, unity

I've removed all the lights in my scene and the ambient lighting. It works fine in the editor play mode but when I run it on my Android or as a standalone player a light source appears. 
The light source seems to be ambient in the PC standalone version and directional in the Android version.

Are there any other options that I have to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I figured it out.
I hadn't added the right scene to the builder.

Comment: Yeah, that'd do it.